# Add icon to the start of Material-UI's Autocomplete component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, autocomplete, material-ui, react-props

I want to add an icon to the beginning of the `Autocomplete` component. (with `startAdornment`)
I read that [Autocomplete](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/) is a normal text input

So far I tried adding

```
InputProps={{startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">kg</InputAdornment>,}}
```

to the `<TextField />` component. Like below:

```
<Autocomplete
            {...defaultProps}
            onChange={(event, value) => {
                handleOnChange(event, value);
            }}
            id="disable-close-on-select"
            sx={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={params => (
                <TextField
                    InputProps={{
                        startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">kg</InputAdornment>,
                    }}
                    {...params}
                    label="search"
                    variant="standard"
                />
            )}
        />
```

Any help would be great, as I'm a beginner to the Material-UI ecosystem.

`defaultProps` is defined like this.

```
const defaultProps = {
    options: data,
    getOptionLabel: (option: DataType) => option?.id,
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prop order matters. Your `InputProps` you define is overridden by the `params.InputProps` from `renderInput`. This:

```
<TextField InputProps={yourProps} {...params}
```

is the same as:

```
<TextField InputProps={yourProps} InputProps={param.InputProps} {...}
```

And the final result is:

```
<TextField InputProps={param.InputProps} {...}
```

You need to define your custom `InputProps` after you spread the `params` and make sure to spread in the nested prop too:

```
renderInput={(params) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      InputProps={{
        ...params.InputProps,
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">kg</InputAdornment>
        )
      }}
      label="Movie"
    />
  );
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: @muratdereköylü Does it not work because of my answer?

Comment: No, it does work. I didn't take all of the parts you shared first. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Where do params come from and when I console log params I see there are 2 input props. one is `inputProps` and another is `InputProps`. Where there are 2 and what are they for?

Comment: @muratdereköylü The `params` is provided from the `Autocomplete` component to setup the `TextField` so that when you interact with it the auto suggestion menu open for you to choose. `inputProps` is used to pass to the native `input` element, `InputProps` is used to pass to the `Input` component inside the `TextField`, which is a wrapper around `input` with MUI flavor.

Comment: @NearHuscarl your idea is correct but it doesn't work when the `Autocomplete` component has the `multiple` prop (the `renderTags` prop would be broken)